# Cell background view not filling the whole cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am using a separate `UITableViewCell` for the `UITableView` and when i set background View of this cell, it seems to fill the image in a box rather than the whole cell. The dimensions of both separate `UITableViewCell` and `UITableView's` row are `280x44`. Here's an image of what it looks like:
[image]

Here's the code that i am writing for setting the background view of the cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// ...

    PBDashboardSummarizedCell *cell = (PBDashboardSummarizedCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PBDashboardSummarizedCell"];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [PBDashboardSummarizedCell standardCell];
    }
     if(datapickup.isexpanded==YES)
          {
           UIImageView *av = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 280, 44)];
              av.opaque = NO;
              av.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dashboardCellEffect.png"]];
              cell.backgroundView = av;          //tried this
             // [cell setBackgroundView:av];     //and this also... but still image is set in the box and not the whole cell
          }
          else{
              UIImageView *av = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 280, 44)];
              av.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
              av.opaque = NO;
              cell.backgroundView = av;

        }

          return cell;
}
```

Comment: try adding image view to cell.contentview

Comment: I tried to fill the imageview to cell's contentview but still the image is appearing in a box

Comment: see the image posted above, the backgroundView image that i have set is not filling the whole cell..

Comment: initWithFrame try changing frames to cell.bounds

Comment: tried cell.bounds but same effect..

Comment: can you highlight which cell is having issue in your image ?

Comment: A Big Lol.... It seemed that the box effect was in the image itself... sorry for wasting all your precious time ..

Comment: lol..... so punishment is vote for all answers! :D

Comment: @CrazyCreator you also post your version of answer and ask him to vote :P afteral hardwork is what matters! :)

Comment: @CrazyCreator enjoy coding ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code. it worked for me.

```
UIImageView * ac= [[UIImageView alloc] init];
ac.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
cell.backgroundView =ac;
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 1):

try this?

```
UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dashboardCellEffect.png"];
UIView *backgroundCellView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 280, 44)];
// redraw the image to fit cell's size
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(backgroundCellView.frame.size, NO, 0.f);
[backgroundImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, backgroundCellView.frame.size.width, backgroundCellView.frame.size.height)];
UIImage *refinedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

[backgroundCellView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:refinedImage]];
cell.backgroundView = backgroundCellView;
```

Comment: Yes, i have dashboardCellEffect.png of 280x44 and 560x88

Comment: hmm try this. `av.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"dashboardCellEffect.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch]];`

Answer (score 1):

you are using imageview so it shows color in only imageview instead of whole cell

you can try below method

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(datapickup.isexpanded==YES)
    {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dashboardCellEffect.png"]];
    }
    else {
         cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }
}
```

tyr above code your problem will solve.